# How can I change a library declaration at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, shared-libraries

In many of my .NET projects I declare library functions that are used globally.  The DLLs that contain these functions are registered when the product is installed so the declaration is simple:

eg.

```
   Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "SomeLib.dll" (ByVal CommonStr As String, ByVal 
   WhichVar As Integer)
```

However, when I'm debugging/developing I often need to explicitly reference the path of the dll like this:

```
   Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "C:\Usethisone\SomeLib.dll" (ByVal CommonStr As String, ByVal 
   WhichVar As Integer)
```

My problem is that I have occasionally forgotten to remove the file path when sending the code to QA so it gets sent back.
So, how can I code this so I don't need to remember to change this path every time I send a project out for testing?  The Declares, of course, are in the declaration section of the class so I can't use any If logic to switch declarations ( eg. If testingfile.txt Exists then use testing declaration).

I've also thought of creating a global dll that I could inherit from - one with the production declarations and one with the testing declarations - but that is a major change at a low level.  I'm afraid it either just wouldn't work, would cause reference issues and/or would not be approved by management.

Any simpler ideas out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Compilation in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/conditional-compilation)

```
#If DEBUG
    Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "C:\Usethisone\SomeLib.dll" (ByVal CommonStr As String, _
        ByVal WhichVar As Integer)
#Else
    Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "SomeLib.dll" (ByVal CommonStr As String, _
        ByVal WhichVar As Integer)
#End If
```

If you use the *Debug* configuration, you get the code for development, if you use the *Release* configuration you get the production version of the code.

Note that the `#If` is evaluated at compile time, not at runtime. Only the matching code is compiled. The other one is discarded.

See also: [#If...Then...#Else Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/if-then-else-directives).

Comment: Just what I was looking for, now I just need to remember to compile for release ... ;)   Actually, further to this, is there a way to generate custom warnings/reminders at compile time?  Like "Warning: You are compiling the Debug version of this project"?

Comment: Note that the Release version is optimized for speed, while the Debug version is optimized to give you best debug experience.

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET as in C# you can use the [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/if-then-else-directives) `#if...#else...#end if` to declare two different versions of your dll, one for the DEBUG compilation and one for the RELEASE compilation

```
#if DEBUG Then
   Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "C:\Usethisone\SomeLib.dll" (ByVal CommonStr As String, ByVal 
   WhichVar As Integer)
#else
   Declare Sub SomeFunction Lib "SomeLib.dll" (ByVal CommonStr As String, ByVal 
   WhichVar As Integer)
#end if
```

Now when you compile to send your app to the QA you just switch to Release and you have the correct implementation to send

Side note: [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937064/dllimport-vs-declare-in-vb-net) at the difference between Declare and the DllImport attribute

Comment: I will endeavor to move to DllImport in the future.  You've likely guessed that I deal with a LOT of legacy code here :)